# Page snapping on scroll-end with pure javascript (for Cordova App)

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have developed a mobile app that has 3 pages.
The pages are laid out in a horizontal line. The user navigates between pages by swiping left or right on the div that contains all 3 pages.

I have already written code that seems to work *sometimes*.

> Please keep in mind that the HTML and CSS i have listed below is
>   simplified for you to get a quicker understanding. The width of each
>   AppPage and the AppPages_Container will be set dynamically via javascript when the app loads.

**HTML**

```
<div id="AppDisplayArea">
  <div id="AppPages_Container" onscroll="get_PagePosition()">
    <div class="AppPage">Page 1</div>
    <div class="AppPage">Page 2</div>
    <div class="AppPage">Page 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#AppDisplayArea{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-x:scroll;} 
#AppPages_Container{position:absolute; z-index:1; top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0; margin:0; width:2160px; height:100%;}
.AppPage{position:relative; width:720px; height:100%; display:block; float:left;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

This is the first function that is called via an onscroll event

```
function get_PagePosition()
{
 var Container = document.getElementById('AppPages_Container'); 
 var scroll_position = Container.scrollLeft;

 var FIRST = 0;
 var SECOND = window.innerwidth;
 var THIRD = window.innerwidth*2;

 var Page1_Position = (Math.abs(FIRST - scroll_position));
 var Page2_Position = (Math.abs(SECOND - scroll_position));
 var Page3_Position = (Math.abs(THIRD - scroll_position));

 var Nearest_Page = Math.min(Page1_Position, Page2_Position, Page3_Position);

 setTimeout(function(){ check_position(); },60);


   function check_position()
    {
      if(Page1_Position==Nearest_Page){SnapPage('Pages_Container',0);}
      if(Page2_Position==Nearest_Page)SnapPage('Pages_Container',1);}
      if(Page3_Position==Nearest_Page)SnapPage('Pages_Container',2);}
    }

}// End get_PagePosition
```

This is the second function that does the actual snapping (with a nested Animate() function)

```
function SnapPage(_object,_position){   

var LEFT = (window.innerWidth*_position);                        
var Page   = document.getElementById(_object);
var Scroll_Speed = 10; 
var Scroll_Direction;
var Count = (Math.abs(Page.scrollLeft - LEFT));
var ScrollTimer = setInterval(function(){ Animate(); }, 1);

if(LEFT > Page.scrollLeft){Scroll_Direction=1;}
if(LEFT < Page.scrollLeft){Scroll_Direction=-1;}
if(LEFT == Page.scrollLeft){Scroll_Direction=0;}

 function Animate()
 { 
  if(Count<=0){clearInterval(ScrollTimer); Page.scrollLeft=LEFT; return;}
  Page.scrollLeft += (Scroll_Direction*Scroll_Speed);  
  Count-=Scroll_Speed; if(Count<0){Count=0;}
 }


return false;              
}//End SnapPage.
```

Is there an easier (more reliable) method for achieving page snapping without the use of a JavaScript Framework??   ...please help by giving suggestions or better solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `onscroll` event, use the `touchstart` and `touchmove` events.

Touch events will provide you with an event that includes an array of touch coordinates, so you can use them to detect swipe.

Keep track of the current view, and change the current div according to the swipe.

So a simple implementation is:

```
var xStart;
var currentScreen = 1;

function onTouchStart(e) {                                         
    xStart = e.touches[0].clientX;                                      
};                                                

function onTouchMove(e) {
    if (!xStart) return;

    if (xStart - e.touches[0].clientX > 0) {
        // Handle left swipe
        currentScreen++;
        if (currentScreen > 3) currentScreen = 1; 
    } else {
        // Handle right swipe
        currentScreen--;
        if (currentScreen < 1) currentScreen = 3; 
    }                       

    xStart = null;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice and compact solution. I have used touch events in earlier versions of my code and they worked well for swapping pages... but they did not work well for real time feedback (user seeing the page move with their finger). EXAMPLE: The YouTube app has 4 tabs (pages) that can be accessed by swiping left or right. If a very small swipe was made on page 1.. then page 1 will slide back into center frame. But if a significant sized swipe was made... then the app will make the transition onto the other page.

Comment: I shall incorporate your touch solution and run some tests, once i get it to work well with the real time feedback i shall return to accept your solution as the main answer to my question. In the mean time i will be sure to upVote your clear and easy to follow solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. Like I wrote, this is a simple implementation, so about what you described with YouTube app, you can achieve this using those events, just need more logic in the event handling, for example: 1) calculate acceleration of the movement to decide if you want to just change to location of the div on the screen, or change the screen 2) use the difference between each move event to change the location of the div... Those events can be used for all of this, it's just more logic.